# Swipe-to-dismiss with coordinatorlayout for recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture, android-coordinatorlayout

Will I need to wrap every swipable element of the recyclerview inside a corresponding coordinatorlayout or can I leverage one coordinatorlayout around the recyclerview?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which approach you're using, but is really simple to create a Swipe to dismiss effect with **ItemTouchHelper**, implementing the ItemTouchHelper.Callback.

This callback is a interface responsible to listen for **swipes** and **moves** on the RecyclerView. [Here](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) you'll see a excellent tutorial on the subject.

You could also use the great [RecyclerView Advanced](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview). It uses a different approach, but works just fine.